# How bright is part of UIImage?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimage

Have a label over part of an `UIImageView`. If image is too bright white text can not read. Any easy way to detect how bright portion of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "easy" way of doing it at least for processor. For developer it is easiest to get access to raw RGBA buffer of image data and find out what is the average color. Then convert that color to HSV and check saturation to determine the brightness. You can even use GPU to make things a bit quicker; openGL should be perfect for that.

But before you get too far: The result will most likely not be what you are looking for. There are always cases that will make your text unreadable no matter what color they are. Consider you have a white text and will convert it to black once image is too bright. But then the image consists purely of black and white stripes so that every odd letter is over white stripe and the rest are on black. The text is simply unreadable.

I suggest you try with stroke, dropping shadows or adding a background. You can for instance have white text on a label and use semitransparent black background color with some layer corner radius. The background will barely be visible on all but the brightest images and text will always be readable.

Comment: Thanks, ended up with stroke :)